# If existence-tropes would be absurd, does this count against trope theory or the theory of existence-as-a-property?

Tags: modal-logic, existence, properties, nothing

I advert to [the word "trope" as used in philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tropes/) and not as used in [narrative analysis](https://tvtropes.org/) (although I can see a reflection of either sense of the word, in the other use). The argument goes:

1. Existence-tropes would be absurd (see below).
2. Suppose that a theory of properties should be able to handle the epistemic possibility that there is an existence-property (an existence operation in predicate, not quantifier, position). Then the theory of tropes is not an adequate theory of properties.
3. Suppose that a theory of existence-as-a-property should be able to handle the epistemic possibility that properties are tropes. Then existence-as-a-property is not an adequate theory of existence.
4. So either trope theory or existence-as-a-property, or both, is/are misguided.

**Reasoning:** please bear with me; this came up as part of my most outlandish attempt yet at an ontological argument for God. Ignoring God in general, though, let us use **G** to generically refer to some-being-or-other:

1. If, "**G** exists," is made true by **G**'s having a property of existence *X*, and *X* is a trope, in particular the trope "**G**'s existence," then **G** exists when it has its particular existence-trope adequately predicated of it.
2. Now *X* will itself either exist or not. To make things worse, suppose that there is another trope, *X*-minus = "**G**'s nonexistence."<sup>∄</sup>
3. Suppose in general that whenever some *A* exists, it is by having its appropriate existence-trope at hand. Assume that *necessary existence* is when *A*'s existence-trope exists but *A*'s nonexistence trope *doesn't* exist. (This was (so to speak) where the Ouija board in my head started communications with the ghost of Anselm.)
4. Accordingly, suppose that when *X* exists, this is because there is some trope *Y* = "*X*'s existence" that *X* occurrently has.
5. Then suppose that *Y* exists, and so because of another trope *Z* = "*Y*'s existence," and so on and on, *ad infinitum et absurdum* (c.f. [Bradley's regress](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bradley-regress/#BradRegrArguAppeReal1893)).
6. Now, in order for every *X*, *Y*, *Z*, ... to exist, those tropes will have to be detached from their counterparts *X*-minus, *Y*-minus, *Z*-minus, etc. Even more delicately, *X*-minus itself either exists or not, so there is some *XX* = "the existence-trope for *X*-minus" and *XX*-minus (the pertinent nonexistence-trope), etc.
7. Although I can't tell, yet, if there's anything *contradictory*/radically unstable about (1) through (6), it just does seem infinitely absurd to me. So existence-tropes are absurd; so either trope theory is derivatively absurd or existence-as-a-property is. QED

[Maurin[??]](https://books.google.com/books?id=4dA3sSlO9a4C&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22existence+tropes%22&source=bl&ots=eo4As1JOSg&sig=ACfU3U1cCjmkAXAfjz_FZ9RNQ01XeNqk_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigv9HIsfGAAxXyIn0KHTEgB2sQ6AF6BAgoEAM#v=onepage&q=%22existence%20tropes%22&f=false) mentions the question of existence-tropes, but does not (at a glance, anyway) bring up such an objection from absurd infinity. [de Ray[22]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363897330_Existence_exists_and_it_is_God) uses the phrase "existence-tropes" in an endnote, more or less in passing (though note the similarity between his self-existent Existence and my *V*-equals-*V*'s-existence below). [Costa[19]](https://books.google.com/books?id=xlmGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=%22existence+tropes%22&source=bl&ots=klqBwjM57W&sig=ACfU3U0LpwOGuKtHJp7gvhMARrPj3G61qw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFvtXTsfGAAxUEoFsKHbp4AW44ChDoAXoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=%22existence%20tropes%22&f=false) talks of "higher order existence tropes," seemingly indicating that any existence-tropes are also higher-order compared to others (not (just) that there are orders of existence tropes themselves), but so far I don't see any reference to a mirror-of-Bradley's-regress, there. **But one might ask about a trope that was its *own* existence-trope,** some *V* = *V*'s existence. Would there have to be terminal (initial), self-looping existence-tropes to salvage trope theory or existence-as-a-property, here? But how would these uphold the existence of other things *A* unless they were something like *V* = *V*'s-and-*A*'s-existence? Seeming absurdity yet again, then.

---

<sup>∄</sup>To be sure, I jumped from "actuality is symmetrical with the diamond and box operations" to "actuality is symmetrical with the truth operation," wherefore I had thought at first that "does not exist" ≠ "does exist not" (since ¬◊ ≠ ◊¬), which I took to demonstrate the presence, in the rest of the toy system, of a substantive nonexistence property. But then I thought, "It is not actually..." *does* equal, "It is actually not..." so either there is no substantive nonexistence property, here, or somehow a local absence of an existence property is *identical to* the presence of a nonexistence property (**how?**).

Comment: From what I understand, on the [most defensible versions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tropes/#PropObje) of the theory, tropes are not properties, nor are they objects or mixtures of the two. They are *sui generis* and there are restrictions on predicating them that might block your regress. Also, even existence as a predicate does not have to be committed to a *single* item predicable of anything that (naively) 'exists'. Indeed, the verb is promiscuous and we have independent reasons to posit different kinds of 'existence' predicates (for concreta and abstracta, say).

Comment: @Conifold I'll be wanting to look into those options/qualifications, because despite my OP question, I also started thinking over an application to iterated modality that seems like it might allow for iterations that don't collapse (and which might mesh with the essentialism-based picture of modal language). It would be frustrating if I couldn't overcome my impression of "absurdity" when such an application is available (maybe I could convince myself that the counter-absurdity of the application outweighs the appearance of Bradley's mirror, though).